# jQuery Datepicker not working on windows 7 phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, datepicker

I have a form with a date field and use JQuery datepicker. This works perfectly on all platforms except on Windows 7 mobile phone.

When you click the field the calendar appears correctly but when you click on it to select a date no date is selected and the calendar remains displayed.

I've searched around for this and see it has happened to others but have not been able to find a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var myDate = new Date();
$('#datepicker1,#datepicker2').datepicker({
    minDate: myDate,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImage: '/......calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onSelect: controlDates
 });

function controlDates(dateStr)
{
    if (this.id == 'datepicker1')
        { $('#datepicker2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); }
    else
        { $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); }
}
```

PART OF MY FORM:

```
<form.....><input type="text" size="8" name="pudate" value="'.$startdate.'" id="datepicker1" title="">
```

Can anybody advise at all? Thanks.

Comment: Just an update - I have fixed this issue by upgrading jQuery to the 1.10.2 version along with using jquery-migrate and also updating jQuery ui to 1.10.3 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update - I have fixed this issue by upgrading jQuery to the 1.10.2 version along with using jquery-migrate and also updating jQuery ui to 1.10.3 version.